# Setting last 8 bytes of char array to __uint64

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm implementing the SHA1 algorithm from the pseudocode on wikipedia.

It says I should append to original length as 64 bits to the message, so I tried the following:

```
// new_message is of type char[] and is 9+ bytes long
*((__int64*)(new_message-8)) = (__int64) length;
```

This makes the new_message's memory corrupt.

Could someone spot the error?

Thanks!

Edit:

Jesus, I'm so stupid. new_message pointed to the start of my array, no wonder it crashed!

Comment: Are you supposed to write it big-endian or little-endian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not definitively, without seeing the part of the code that shows what `new_message` is set to.

It looks like you are underflowing the buffer though, which will mess up the heap header that probably precedes `&new_message[0]`.  You are writing your `__int64` 8 bytes before the start of the `char[]`, by the look of things.

Comment: @monoceres - I am +1-ing your question in honor of the brutality of your self-appraisal.  Everybody's been there.

Answer (score 3):

new_message-8
would go back 8 bytes from the current pointer, is that the intention is ?
append would mean to add 8 bytes at the end, you need to make sure
1> You have enough memory (8 extra bytes) at the end.
2> your pointer is pointing to the correct place (where to append)